# Angular UI Calendar with Google Calendar v3 API integration issues

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am currently trying to integrate the Angular UI Calendar into my project with the Google Calendar API.

I have run it successfully with the v3 Calendar API through the jQuery plugin version through FullCalendar alone. However, I need to utilize this in a modal which will not load the calendar properly because the modal is not visible when the calendar attempts to load.

So UI calendar looks like my best option but when I looked into the Docs and Demo I found this:

```
/* event source that pulls from google.com */
$scope.eventSource = {
        url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
};
```

Which points to a google calendar feeds url that returns a 403 error and utilizes feeds from the v1 and v2 Calendar API which are deprecated now.

So I am looking to see if anyone else has run into this problem and if they have found a solution or a workaround

Comment: As you said V2 is deprecated, try changing the scope related to calendar v3 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly. Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680738/api-oauth-google-integration-access-error-origin-mismatch-for-google-calendar

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by another developer having a similar issues with the new calendar API. Make sure to check the versions that are being brought in by the install of FullCalendar and UI Calendar. The gcal.js file was an extremely outdated version and did not support V3 of google calendar.

Also be aware that unless you plan on rewriting the majority of the directive they have provided you will be required to use $scope to get it working. So if you have the preference of using the 'this' methodology just be aware of this disconnect